# How to replace character strings in a column of a dataframe?

Tags: r, string

I have a dataframe with a column that includes these character strings:

```
Rear-Naked Choke 
Submission (Rear-Naked Choke 
Rear Naked Choke
```

Example:

```
                  Method
1             Rear-Naked Choke
2             Rear Naked Choke
3             Rear Naked Choke
4 Submission (Rear-Naked Choke
5             Rear Naked Choke
6             Rear Naked Choke
```

I want them all to be `"Rear-Naked Choke"` so that I can count all under one category. In other words, I just want the entire column to read `"Rear-Naked Choke"`.

Desired output:

```
                  Method
1             Rear-Naked Choke
2             Rear-Naked Choke
3             Rear-Naked Choke
4             Rear-Naked Choke
5             Rear-Naked Choke
6             Rear-Naked Choke
```

What I tried:

> str_replace_all(c("Rear-Naked Choke" = "Rear-Naked Choke", "Submission
>   (Rear-Naked Choke)" = "Rear-Naked Choke", "Rear Naked Choke)" =
>   "Rear-Naked Choke"))

And:

> gsub("Submission (Rear-Naked Choke)", "Rear-Naked Choke",
>   data$column)

gsub doesn't work when I want to replace `"("`.

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Include a `dput()` of your data so we know exactly what's in the column. Show the code you tried.

Comment: Do you just want the entire column to read "Rear-Naked Choke"?

Comment: I'd do something like `x[grepl("Rear-Naked Choke", x)] <- "Rear-Naked Choke"`. That will replace any values that contain the phrase with the phrase itself.

Comment: Your replacement of `(` isn't working because it's a regex special character. You can either escape it with two backslashes in the pattern or set `fixed = T` if you are looking for an exact match and not using fancy regex.

Comment: Gregor, that solution worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace a special character in R you have to make it this way:

```
gsub("\\(","","(hello") #This will give you "hello"
```

My recomendation for your problem is that first get rid of every special chacrater with `gsub` like this:

```
df$mycol <- gsub("[[:punct:]]","",df$mycol)
```

then after that it will be easier for you to replace any string in the column.

type `?regex` in your R console for more information.